# What is the difference between python function and python module

Tags: python

I am a beginner of python i didn't found any difference between function and module.it is said that module stores code even after shutting the shell off rather than function.but when i tried to do so it didn't work for me.SO what is the big deal of using a module rather than function in the programming

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Answer (score 3):

In programming, function refers to a segment that groups code to perform a specific task.

A module is a software component or part of a program that contains one or more routines.

That means, functions are groups of code, and modules are groups of classes and functions.