# PyLint/PyLint3 does not recognize docstrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, docstring

I wrote several Python 3 modules of the following format:

```
def some_module():
'''Do something.

Parameters
----------
Returns
-------
'''
# Some code
```

When I run PyLint or PyLint3 over the file, I get the following error:

> ************* Module some_module.some_module
>   C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)

What am I doing wrong? Does PyLint require a specific docstring style?

Comment: Your example is a function docstring, pylint asks you to document the module itself.

Comment: As I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878730/what-is-the-difference-between-python-function-and-python-module), functions contain reusable code for specific tasks, while modules are bundles of functions, classes etc. But in this case, all modules consist of only a single function, so there is no need for a module-level docstring. Is PyLint able to understand this? Or should even simple functions have both a module and a function docstring? Or should I avoid creating too many functions and rather bundle them into modules?

Comment: Also, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557110/what-to-put-in-a-python-module-docstring) discussion it's not clear what differentiates function docstrings from module docstrings. Could it be that PEP 8 and PEP 257 are only relevant for the organization of large projects and have only limited value for small scripts?

Comment: Put simply, modules are .py files. Pylint doesn't really "understand" anything, it simply checks (statically) your code against a bunch of rules. In particular, `missing-docstring` checks that modules, classes and functions have docstrings (i.e. `__doc__`). Whether you want to enforce these rules or not is up to you. For example, I've found `too-few-public-methods` to be pretty useless, so I usually disable it.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you fix "Missing module docstringpylint(missing-module-docstring)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949325/how-do-you-fix-missing-module-docstringpylintmissing-module-docstring)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried indenting the doc-string, so it identified as part of the module?

```
def some_module():
    '''Do something.

    Parameters
    ----------
    Returns
    -------
    '''
    # Some code
    ...
```