# How to remove this warning from VScode python code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In my python code, I see the following warning all over the place;

```
Missing function or method docstringpylint(missing-function-docstring)
```

How do I remove this warning?

I am using VS code v1.64.0, Microsoft Python Extension for Visual Studio Code v2022.0.1786462952.

Comment: i suppose this warning is seen in the bottom dock where the `PROBLEMS` are shown in VS Code. that section usually also shows the name of the file the warning is being raised from. I would ask you to check the filename that it shows just above this warning that you are receiving. if it doesn't point to the file that u are editing, its probably not worth your concern.

Comment: however, if this _does_ cause you hindrance (by not running it at all) in running any of your scripts, there might be a bigger problem with the installation of your linter that you might have to solve.. anything more than this can only be said if u can post a screenshot of the problems section (where you see this warning) of your VS Code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949325/how-do-you-fix-missing-module-docstringpylintmissing-module-docstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the hints provided in the comments, I managed to find an answer to my question.

Edit settings.json found in .vscode folder.

Add in the following;

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0116",        
    ],    
}
```

My answer was found thanks to another answer here
[How do you fix "Missing module docstringpylint(missing-module-docstring)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949325/how-do-you-fix-missing-module-docstringpylintmissing-module-docstring/65951135#65951135)