# Missing module docstringPylint(C0114:missing-module-docstring), pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the plugin pylint. But I get some errors. Like this error:

```
Missing module docstringPylint(C0114:missing-module-docstring)
```

and this error:

```
Formatting a regular string which could be a f-stringPylint(C0209:consider-using-f-string)
```

and this is my settings.json file in visual studio code:

```
  "python.linting.enabled": true,

  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=line-too-long",
    "--disable=unused-argument",
    "--disable=C0111",
    "--errors-only"
  ],
```

and this is the code fragment where the errors occur:

```
class Leg:
    pass


class Back:
    pass


class Chair:
    def __init__(self, num_legs):
        self.legs = [leg() for leg in range(num_legs)]
        self.back = Back()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "I have {} and one back".format(len(self.legs))


print(Chair(5))
```

and of course I googled this. But the suggestion I found on the net is that I have to change the settings of python.linting as described above. But no change is detecetd.

And I also restarted vs code a couple of times.

So does somebody know how to tackle this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (C0209:consider-using-f-string)

> C0114:missing-module-docstring

I believe you have read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949325/how-do-you-fix-missing-module-docstringpylintmissing-module-docstring). You can add the following content to disable these string warnings:

```
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0114",
    "--disable=C0209",
  ],
```

Comment: Using latest VS Code, and not seeing these options -- any ideas? (I believe I have all relevant python extensions, like 'Python' and 'Pylint')