# How can I remove Pylint' s Missing module docstring Problem in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm new at python and i downloaded program today. I tried to say hello world but i got this problem after run and debug:

> Missing module docstring Pylint(C0114:missing-module-docstring)

so in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949325/how-do-you-fix-missing-module-docstringpylintmissing-module-docstring/73986545#73986545) question @ikhvjs is said that he used this code. But i don't know where and how do i need to write this code in a code line in my user settings. I tried to find videos on the net but i couldn't.

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
      "--disable=missing-module-docstring",
      "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
      "--disable=missing-function-docstring"
    ]
```

my user settings in vscode:

```
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "name": "One Dark italic",
                "scope": [
                    "comment",
                    "entity.other.attribute-name",
                    "keyword",
                    "markup.underline.link",
                    "storage.modifier",
                    "storage.type",
                    "string.url",
                    "variable.language.super",
                    "variable.language.this"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "One Dark italic reset",
                "scope": [
                    "keyword.operator",
                    "keyword.other.type",
                    "storage.modifier.import",
                    "storage.modifier.package",
                    "storage.type.built-in",
                    "storage.type.function.arrow",
                    "storage.type.generic",
                    "storage.type.java",
                    "storage.type.primitive"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Dark SynthWave '84",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    }
}
```

I tried to wrote after "[python]" like this:

```
"[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true ,
        "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=missing-module-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-function-docstring"
        ]
    }
}
```

but it didn't work. Now vs code PROBLEMS saying "Unknown editor configuration setting" how can i disable this missing module docstring? Do i need to uninstall pylint?

Comment: is it valid to use `--disable` like that? (`--disable=foo --disable=bar --disable=baz`) Is it not `--disable=foo,bar,baz`? [From the docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/usage/run.html#command-line-options): "_You can disable a specific checker or some of its messages or message categories by specifying --disable=<symbol>. \[...\] with <symbol> being a comma-separated list of checker names and message symbols._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This setting cannot be applied because it is not registered as language override setting.

This setting cannot be set within a language. You can add it at the end of your settings, like this:

```json
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Dark SynthWave '84",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=missing-module-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
        "--disable=missing-function-docstring"
    ]
```

Comment: Can this be done in .pylintrc file as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `settings.json` under `.vscode` folder.

[image]

Add these codes to the `settings.json`:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
      "--disable=missing-module-docstring",
      "--disable=missing-class-docstring",
      "--disable=missing-function-docstring"
    ]
```

Another way is trying to use [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) as the language Server:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a docstring at the top of your module.
example
"""
This module provides a function to calculate the factorial of a number.
"""